# Ionic2 - Base64 PDF

Tags: android, rest, cordova, base64, ionic2

I am currently developing a mobile project using Cordova and Ionic2 using an external database resource that connects to the mobile via REST webServices.

The database has documents pdf saved that you have to send to the mobile and view the same. I am using the pdf in enconding Base64 through the webservices by Json.

I can get the string in base64, but I do not quite understand how to decode it and save it on mobile, which is Android to be able to see it.

Comment: byte bytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.ENCODING_DEFAULT); Then save the bytes to file.

Comment: It seems that base64 dont exist :\

Answer (score 0):

Use the native **File** component from Ionic 2.

- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
- npm install --save @ionic-native/file

To save the base64 string on the device you call the **createFile(path, fileName, replace)** method.

More info: [Ionic 2 File](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar battle with PDF's, but dealing with them in binary/Blob form.  Similar problem/solution overall.  It seems that PDF opening isn't as simple as it should be across Web/Android/iOS.

[Open createObjectURL Blob on Cordova InAppBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224447/open-createobjecturl-blob-on-cordova-inappbrowser/)