# Open createObjectURL Blob on Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, pdf, blob

I have an Angular2+/Cordova app, and I'm making an API request to get a PDF.  I'd like to open this PDF in Web + Native environments.

For web I'm opening the window, getting the PDF & creating a Blob from it, then doing `createObjectURL` and setting the window's `location.href` to that URL.  It works well (on Chrome/FF).

On native I'd like to do something similar, but ideally just do a window.open (via the `InAppBrowser` plugin) with the URL that came from `createObjectURL`.  Is this possible?  The URL I get back is something like: `blob:file:///ef76ad0d-7c7f-4817-915f-9097160d1a58`.  Trying to open this via InAppBrowser with a `_system` target does absolutely nothing.  No errors, no windows, no nothing.  Wondering if there are special whitelist or SCP things I need to do for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, I don't like this solution, but I ended up treating web and native differently in this case.

WEB:
Open Window --> REST call to get Blob --> createObjectURL with Blob --> set window location href to result of previous step

NATIVE:
REST call to get Blob --> Save Blob with Cordova File plugin --> Open saved file with Cordova File Opener plugin

Comment: 4.5 years later, we ended up doing the exact same thing. Thanks :)