# How to open a generated blob of a PDF in the default browser in a cordova app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am generating a PDF inside my cordova app that I am then displaying to the user. I want to open this PDF in the default browser so that the user can download it. Once the PDF is generated, I am retrieving the blob data. I am then hooking the InAppBrowser plugin into `window.open` and opening the PDF like this:

`window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), '_blank')`

This correctly opens the PDF inside the in app browser inside my app. However, when I try to do the following to open it in the mobile phones default browser, nothing happens:

`window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), '_system')`

I am pretty sure this is because the format of the blob looks something like this `blob:httpsionic://localhost/c0c70f84-6b6c-461c-92b8-1b6fac336cdd` which I am assuming is the problem since I can open test PDFs correctly using the `_system` option. Is there something I can do to transform the blob into a format that I will be able to open with the `_system` option and have the PDF open in the default browser? I tried converting the blob to base64 data and opening that, but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224447/open-createobjecturl-blob-on-cordova-inappbrowser

Comment: Can you tell us what you ended up doing in this case? Thanks!

Comment: We went in a different direction and used a cordova print plugin

Comment: Nice, we ended up saving the blob to app storage (using `window.requestFileSystem`, `fs.root.getFile`, `fileEntry.createWriter`, `fileWriter.write(blob)`) and then opening it on `fileWriter.onwriteend` via `cordova-plugin-file-opener2`.
Do you think this would qualify as an answer? (with a more comprehensive explanation / code sample of course) Thanks!