# How do I generate/preview pdf in Android using jsPDF in a cordova app

Tags: android, vue.js, cordova, jspdf, html-framework-7

Long story short, I'm developing an app using (Framework7, VueJS, Cordova).
I need to generate and preview a pdf file using jsPDF; this works normally when I test on the browser, but when I build the app to test it on Android, nothing happens when I try to generate the PDF.

Here are the lines responsible for the pdf generation part:

```
    var blobPDF =  new Blob([ doc.output() ], { type : 'application/pdf'});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF);
    window.open(url);
```

Comment: Have you tried the debugger in Chrome to see if you get any error messages?

Comment: No error was shown in devtools, as I said, it works fine on the browser (I can preview the generated pdf). But when I test it on my Android phone, nothing happens (The blob file is created, but when I try to preview it using window.open, nothing happens)

Comment: It might be that you need to use InAppBrowser - per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66249683/how-to-open-a-generated-blob-of-a-pdf-in-the-default-browser-in-a-cordova-app

Try logging the blob. Also it seems that doc.output takes different parameters. Check that you are producing the expected value. https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html#output

Comment: I'm using InAppBrowser, I tested to open google.com and it worked, but when I try the blob file preview, it doesn't open on my device (although it works on my PC's browser).. Plus, I've been testing with all of jsPDF's parameters to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display a pdf document into a Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview)

Comment: I need the app to work offline, so using Google Docs as a medium isn't an option. I think this has something to do with permissions and navigation parameters via AndroidManifest.xml and Config.xml, but I still haven't solved the issue