# Ionic - Open a BLOB URL using InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am using the ionic framework and I am generating a PDF file in my application and for the PDF file, I get the following type of blob URL generated by my code.

```
blob:http://localhost:3002/f5e4fb56-5510-4e57-abcc-73688871842f
```

I am trying to open that blob both in `android` and `web` platforms. Now for the web part, it opens the PDF file successfully in the browser tab, but for android, it does nothing. No errors, no warnings, and the browser doesn't show up.

I have also visited [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224447/open-createobjecturl-blob-on-cordova-inappbrowser/46536596) answer, but it didn't work for me

Here is how I am doing it:

**Adding an instance of InAppBrowser:**

[image: Adding an instance of InAppBrowser]

**Using InAppBrowser to open the generated PDF URL**

[image: Using InAppBrowser to open the generated PDF url]

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @MiguelPosadas I had to go for a different method

Comment: @AhmadHabib, could you suggest what is the different method?

Comment: Using a 3rd party module "PDFGenerator"